# Error: aspnet_wp.exe (PID: 332) stopped unexpectedly.,

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting 3errors . this is the event log

Type: Error Event: 1089
User: N/A
Computer: HOME-590392F5B5
1) aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: 332) stopped unexpectedly.
2) Failed to execute the request because the ASP.NET process identity does not have read permissions to the global assembly cache. Error: 0x80131902 
3) Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT

Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException

Message: Exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' was thrown.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.Configuration.ErrorRuntimeConfig.ErrorConfigRecord.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigRecord.GetLkgSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfigLKG.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_HostingEnvironment()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.StartMonitoringForIdleTimeout()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters

I see many posts about this on the internet but only the error..

Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks
SC

Comment: What version of iis are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your 3 error messages,  it appears the account that you are running your application pool under has not been granted sufficient access.

What account are your running your application pool under?  Also which version of IIS are you running on?   The details change based on the answer to the above two